$_GET[''] variable with nonce verification
How to use $_GET[''] variable in WordPress plugin development with nonce verification ?
My code is like below.
if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'weather_info') || ($_GET['page'] === 'weather_info_page') || ($post_type === 'weather_info' && $_GET['action'] === 'edit')) {  

How can I use $_GET[''] variable with nonce verification in above code ?

There are two ways of creating nonce verification for $_GET parameters:

If you are coming from a form, you can use the wp_nonce_field function to create your own field. For example:

<form action="edit.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="example">
  .....
  <?php wp_nonce_field('my_custom_action', 'my_custom_name'); ?>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


If you are coming from a link you created, use the wp_create_nonce function:

$url = admin_url('edit.php?post_type=weather_info&.....&my_custom_nonce=' . wp_create_nonce('my_custom_action'));

And processing the nonce verification at both cases, within your own code happens with the wp_verify_nonce function:
if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && ..... ) && wp_verify_nonce($_GET['my_custom_nonce'], 'my_custom_action')) {
  .....
}

WordPress offers the Plugin Check (PCP) plugin, that checks for potential issues. In there they also suggest to do a sanitization and unslashing for nonce fields, so actually this would be the final form of how it should be used:
if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && ..... ) && wp_verify_nonce(sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($_GET['my_custom_nonce'])), 'my_custom_action')) {
  .....
}


Thanks @Mowar. But there is no nonce field in my code.if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'weather_info') || ( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] === 'weather_info_page' ) || ($post_type === 'weather_info' && (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'edit'))) { . I am using Plugin Check Plugin.  Thanks.
